# Competing notions of formal étaleness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, definitions, synthetic-differential

I'm writing some notes to myself on algebraic geometry and I'm trying to get the most conceptual definitions. Having arrived at formally étale morphisms, I am pretty desperate.

Here is a list of definitions for an arrow $f$ to be étale.

1. SDG I - [Kock's SDG book](http://home.math.au.dk/kock/sdg99.pdf), section I.17, and [Kostecki's notes](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/sdg.pdf), definition 8.10, "specialized" to our case (take the small object to be just $D=\operatorname{Spec}_RR[\epsilon]$), ask for the square below to be a pullback
   $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
       TM @>{df}>> TN\\ @V{\pi}VV @VV{\pi^\prime}V\\
       M @>>{f}> N
       \end{CD}$$
   Geometrically, this seems like the most intuitive - identifying the tangent bundle of $M$ with the tangents of $N$ with basepoints in the image of $f$. By pullback pasting this implies also $df:T_xX\cong T_{f(x)}Y$.
2. SDG II - Rephrasing the pullback as a strong left lifting property, $f:M\rightarrow N$ is étale if it has the unique right lifting property w.r.t to the point $0:\mathsf{1}\rightarrow D$:
   $$\array{
       \mathsf{1} &\longrightarrow& M
       \\
       \downarrow &\nearrow& \downarrow
       \\
       D &\longrightarrow& N
     }$$ This doesn't look intuitive to me, but whatever if it's formally equivalent to 1.
3. Algebraic Geometry I - a morphism of affine schemes $f:\operatorname{Spec}B\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}A$ is étale if it has the unique right lifting property against infinitesimal extensions, i.e (opposites of) regular epimorphisms $\hat R\twoheadrightarrow R$ with nilpotent kernel:
   $$\array{
       \operatorname{Spec}R &\longrightarrow& \operatorname{Spec}B
       \\
       \downarrow &\nearrow& \downarrow
       \\
       \operatorname{Spec}\hat R &\longrightarrow& \operatorname{Spec}A
     }$$
   This definition seems conceptual, but I don't really understand why it should be related to the much more intuitive notion of local diffeomorphism. Why should local diffeomorphisms "extend to infinitesimal neighborhoods"?

> Are definitions 1 and 3 equivalent or related in some useful setting? How to move between them?

**Added.** If we do not specialize 1 to second-order infinitesimals and instead take the definition asking the square below to be a pullback for generalized tangent space ($W$ is a Weil algebra), are 1 and 3 equivalent?
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    M^{D(W)} @>>> N^{D(W)}\\ @VVV @VVV\\
    M @>>{f}> N
    \end{CD}$$

Comment: 1 is the special case of 3 with $\hat R=\operatorname{Spec}R[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: With respect to definition (3): you should think of $\textrm{Spec}\hat R$ as some kind of tubular neighbourood of $\textrm{Spec}R$, so the property is saying that you can lift (small enough) tubular neighbouroods along local diffeomorphisms. If you think about it for a while you'll see that this is more or less equivalent to being a local diffeomorphism

Comment: In algebraic geometry, the morphism $f$ needs to be locally of finite presentation in order to be étale.  Without that condition, you have the notion called "formally étale".

Comment: One thing that helped me concetualizing this is the following analogies: formally smooth ~ submersion, formally unramified ~ immersion, formally etale ~ local isomorphism. To get rid of the formally we just add "locally of finite presentation" which is equivalent to requiring that upon restricting to open affines we get that one affine is a compact object in the category of algebras over the other (using commutation with filtered colimits we can lift morphisms from local rings to open sets - this is the main application I've seen to this finiteness condition).

Comment: (1) somehow suggests that the liftings in (2) and (3) must be unique. How does this follow?

Comment: As Marc Hoyois pointed out, (1) is the special case of (3) for infinitesimals of order $2$. For a morphism of smooth algebraic varieties, (1) implies (3), i.e., lifting of infinitesimals of order $2$ implies that of infinitesimals of all orders (is this your question? I'm not sure): the key word here is "Jacobian criterion of étaleness", it's probably hidden somewhere in EGA IV₄ but the key point is Hensel's lemma: once you can lift at the lowest order, the other orders follow. For singular varieties, the lowest order may not suffice.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I updated my question forgoing the omission of higher order infinitesimals.

Comment: @MarcHoyois could you please post a formal proof as an answer?

Comment: I think people are confused (at least, I am) as to what exactly you're asking for. Do you agree that (1) and (2) are equivalent for $D=\mathrm{Spec}R[\varepsilon]$? Do you agree that (2) and (3) are equivalent for $R$-algebras with $\hat R=R[\varepsilon]$ (so that $\mathrm{Spec}R=1$ and $\mathrm{Spec}\hat R=D$)? I think that's what @MarcHoyois was pointing out to you. So I thought your question was about how to lift to higher order infinitesimals (and I tried to clarify this in my comment), but now it seems that it's not...

Comment: @MarcHoyois I don't quite see (3) $\Rightarrow$ (1). Existence of the lift only gives it is a $\textit{weak}$ pullback, in order for it to be (strict) pullback the lifts must be unique, does it follow?

Comment: I agree that one should have unique lifts, otherwise you are probably only characterising submersions of arbitrary relative dimension.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I edited the question by adding 'unique' where necessary. This was originally intended but I forgot that 'lifting property' without qualification means 'weak lifting property'.

Comment: The question is not whether local diffeomorphisms extend to infinitesimal neighbourhoods, but the other way around: why should a map that induces an isomorphism on infinitesimal neighbourhoods of points in fact be a local diffeomorphism? For finite-dimensional smooth manifolds in the usual setup this is because one can construct charts from tangent spaces using the exponential map.